# Does MAF has something to do with rough idle?

Tags: mazda, rough-idle, maf

I am trying to solve my cars long issue in idles again.
Cleaning the ICV did the trick before but it keeps coming back and I don't know what else to check. Here's the link in my [previous question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27701/car-stalls-on-intersection-or-when-coming-to-a-stop).

What I did was to replace the intake filters, change oil and now looking at MAF sensors.
Is this related or even worth the try? If so, is it okay to clean MAF using MAF cleaner? 
Can I use electronic contact cleaners too? Is there really a gain in cleaning MAF and other contacts around the intake system?

What I already did:

1. Change spark plugs
2. Changed oil
3. changed filters (air and oil filters)
4. check leaks - no leak
5. heat sensors - I think it is fine, I have no check engine

Apologies if I have a lot of questions. If anyone can point to possible solution, I'd appreciate it.

Note: I stumble on this [site](http://knowhow.napaonline.com/know-how-notes-how-to-clean-your-maf-sensor/) while googling for what to check. And so I ask here for confirmation.

Comment: Have you tried connecting an OBD2 reader to see if the MAF is returning sensible values?

Comment: I'd be tempted to re-route the crankcase breather into a catch can instead of back into the air box.

Comment: @handyhowie I don't have that and that is way technical for me but I appreciate the response.

Comment: @stevematthews Is that the little hose on top of the crankcase going to the intake pipe? what do I do with it? and what is a catch can? thanks appreciate it.

Comment: This hose releases excess oil pressure from the engine block / sump so you get hot, oily air coming out of the pipe.  The emissions laws for all brand new vehicles state this must not exhaust to atmosphere.  However, once a vehicle is in use, these regulations do not apply.  A catch can is a part fitted to performance and Motorsport vehicles to catch excess oil from the oil breather so it doesn't get sucked into the air box.  This hot oily air may be what is fouling your ISV.

Comment: @SteveMatthews yeah I get it now. So I would need to install one. Cause considering the cars age (18+ yrs), "blow by" might really be a factor. Ok that is for the clogging of ISV, and so do you think the MAF needs cleaning too cause that is part of that system where the breather is connected.

Comment: Installing one wouldn’t hurt.  Always clean MAF mesh with electrical contact cleaner as it leaves no deposits which can interfere with its operation.

Comment: Residue free electronic contact cleaner is perfectly fine, you don't need the specialized cleaner. I used two electronic cleaners from different brands on my MAF and it's still working perfectly.